# JSON get and show on html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

i'm making a web app, and i need to get data from JSON files and print them in form of a table.
Problem is that i'm getting a 404 error, JSON file (actually i work on local and doing a Node.js).

*Edit 1:*
while looking to network tab i get to see the 404 error. the JSON File is in text/file.json and the index.ejs is in views/index.ejs . So my question is that i can't get any data when trying to get the JSON file (doesn't find it).

the app is on a local server made with node.js and express.

the tree of my files

- text/allfiles.json
- public/
- routes/index.js
- views/index.ejs
- app.js

Here are my files :
**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $.getJSON("/text/global_summary.json", function(data) {
            console.log("JSON Data opened");
            $.each(data, function(i, field) {
                var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + field.topic + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + field.page + "</td>"
                $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
            });

        });
    });
</script>
.
.
.
<div class="container">
  <table id= "userdata" border="2">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id">Topic</th>
      <th data-field="name">Page</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**my json file**

```
  [{"topic": "INTRODUCTION", "page": 8}, {"topic": "THE UNIVERSE", "page": 10}]
```

thanks.

Comment: Did you try pressing f12 in a browser and looking at the network tab?

Comment: Where is your index file in relation to your json file?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Are you serving the json file through node.js as well? There's a good possibility that this is a server side error, so we'll need details on your server setup (which you seem to indicate is the local machine running node.js, which is fine, but without the server-side code we're only seeing half the equation.

Comment: @ChristopherPeart while looking to network tab i get to see the 404 error.
the JSON File is in text/file.json
and the index.ejs is in views/index.ejs .
So my question is that i can't get any data when trying to get the JSON file (doesn't find it).

Comment: @ashbygeek for now it's a local server made with node.js, which server code do you want to see exactly ? routes ? thanks.

Comment: yes, definitely post any `app.get(...)` routes and if you're using express, then any `app.use(...)` statements. Also, if you could describe the pertinent bits of your file tree that would be good. And please edit your original post with the new details rather than putting them in a comment, these details will be pertinent to anyone else who might try to give an answer.

Comment: do i need to create a app.get (...) in order to return the JSON file so i can use it ? or can i load it directly with JQuery ?

Comment: your node.js app must serve it some way or another. More details in my answer that I will post shortly.

Comment: Also, for future reference, if you had posted the contents of your app.js file at the beginning we would have gotten to the answer a lot sooner. Every webpage has two sides, the client side (the html and javascript running in your browser), and the server side (in this case nodejs and your app.js script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check if you can view/download the json file by putting its url directly into the browsers url window.

If that doesn't work (404 strongly suggests this), your express app is not serving the json file and you have to either add static file providing or add a route for the json file.

Also: is your app hosted at the root of the webserver? Because a url starting with / adresses files at the root of the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a base to your head tag:

```
<base href="http://localhost/" target="_blank">
```

If you still faced 404 post the request header here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that you aren't actually serving the json file. When your code calls `$.getJSON("/text/global_summary.json"...);` the browser doesn't magically know where to get the file, it asks your server to send it that file. Your server doesn't know either, so it just says 'error 404', which means 'I don't know'.

So you must tell your server how to serve that static file. Since you are using express, this is really easy. Just add

```
app.use('/text', express.static('text'))
```

to your app.js file and any time your server gets a request for any '/text/somefile.extension' it will try to find it in your text folder. There's a really good rundown of how to serve files this way here: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html.